# ansible YAML regex filter

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to extract guid value of API response, here is a sample of the response:

```
"api_request.json": {
        "message": "\"Role name 'mgmt-ALERTPUBLISHER-uuid-placeholder' is not compliant. Use 'mgmt-ALERTPUBLISHER-b7d445b08a96e7f19ff0ff005686cddd', or do not use a name of the format <service name>-<roletype>-<arbitrary value>.\""
    }
```

Here is my regex:

```
<div>\p{Any}*?</div>|[0-9a-f]{32}
```

How can I use regex with YAML?

I have only found `regex_replace` and `regex_escape` but not pure regex matcher.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex_replace should do the trick.

This is the code. I'm basically searching for the 'ALERTPUBLISHER-' string and cutting the 32-character string behind it, [keeping it in a named group](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) (just above the note) and using it afterwards in the output.
I noticed your API is in json, if you have the possibility it might be handy if you ask for an additional field with only the uuid string. That will be much more robust than any regex.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    message: "\"Role name 'mgmt-ALERTPUBLISHER-uuid-placeholder' is not compliant. Use 'mgmt-ALERTPUBLISHER-b7d445b08a96e7f19ff0ff005686cddd', or do not use a name of the format <service name>-<roletype>-<arbitrary value>.\""

  pre_tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ message | regex_replace('^.*ALERTPUBLISHER-(?P<uuid>.{32}).*$', '\\g<uuid>') }}"
```

This gives me the following output

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "b7d445b08a96e7f19ff0ff005686cddd"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```